# Get a div in center of a line

Tags: html, css

I am new to css.
I am actually trying to display three divs on a single line with one element of the left of the page , 2nd element in the middle of the page and 3rd element on the right side of the page.
Here is my script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    #name {
        color: black;
        display: inline;
    }
    #group {
        color: black;
        display: inline;
        float: right;
    }
    #cent {
        color: black;
        display: inline;
    }
</style>

<div id="name" style="color: #000000;">EXAMPLE</div>
<div id="group" style="color: #000000;">GROUP</div>
<div id="cent">TEST</div>
```

Here , the output should be

```
EXAMPLE                         TEST                                    GROUP
```

but the output being displayed in

```
EXAMPLE TEST                                                  GROUP
```

Can anyone help me please fix this .TIA

Comment: You should add a `width: 33.33333%` and float all elements to `left`.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it ... float&width, display:inline-block&width, display:table-cell & width, using flexbox, using css columns .... Study some layout tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
#name, #group, #cent {float: left; width: 33.3333%}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try **Flexbox** [`Demo 2`](https://jsfiddle.net/p6x2f31a/) [`Demo 3`](https://jsfiddle.net/p6x2f31a/1/) [`Browser Support`](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="name">EXAMPLE</div>
  <div id="group">GROUP</div>
  <div id="cent">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when we can use `float` or `inline-block`, why using flexbox with limited browser support than the 2 mentioned??? Even using `display: table` is preferred than flexbox in this case.

Comment: It is a valid answer

Comment: Yes, but considering browser painting performance it is not good to be offered without mentioning the limits

Comment: @FarzadYZ that  support issue is quickly dissolving ..especially since microsoft dropped supporting older IE

Answer (score 1):

Add widths.  Float each one to the left of its successor.  Floats generally need widths when used as columns.

```
#name { color: black; float:left; width:33%;}
#group { color: red; float:left; width:34%;}
#cent { color: green; float:left; width:33%}
```